# How to determine which scope-id to use

Tags: tcp, ipv6

Working on a Qt application that tries to connect to a remote, but local server.
The information I have is the IPv6 link-local address to use and the TCP port number

Problem is, when using link-local addresses, you must set the right scope-id, which is the name of the interface connected to the network shared with the remote server.

Say I know the server IPv6 link-local address as being fe80::7273:cbff:fed6:e937 on port 5000.
To connect to it I would need to use the IP address:
fe80::7273:cbff:fed6:e937%en1

Where en1 is the interface name.

If there's only one network card, it's an easy job, can simply always use that interface name as scope id.
But difficulties come when there's more than one!

What is the best way to discover which interface to use to connect to a particular remote link-local address?

While it's a Qt based app, the problem isn't limited to Qt obviously.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance